# Is there any advantage to using WEBrick in development mode for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, webrick

I develop on a Mac, and I'm pretty comfortable setting up an Ubuntu VM with Apache installed, so "you don't need to install Apache" is not really a reason. I run Ruby from the VM anyway, so there doesn't seem to be much difference in system resources needed.

In my head, the advantage of using Apache is that it's going to perform more consistently with my production server.

So what reasons are there to use WEBrick? Does it make development easier somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for phusion passenger + passsenger pref pane: http://www.fngtps.com/2008/06/putting-the-pane-back-into-deployment

Awesomeness. This way I can act more like the production server and take it easy when adding new projects etc.

Comment: I'm actually using Passenger, and I'm happy with it so far.

Answer (score 3):

No there are no advantages.  The only "advantage" is that it is the pre-bundled webserver so you at least "have something"

I'm sure most experienced Ruby devs use something else like thin, mongrel, unicorn, pow, passenger, etc...

Comment: So it would be fair to say that it allows people who can't set up Apache to still use Rails?

Comment: i guess, if you want to look at it that way.  Really, its there so you dont need to configure an apache vhost entry just to run your code in development mode.  Its really more an ease of use thing than anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Rails for a school project, and I find the colorized logs helpful when I'm trying to figure out what the server is doing. Sure you could `tail -f` the apache logs, but color is nice IMO.

Comment: Colorized logs are nice, but also possible with Apache. I guess that's the point about WEBrick - it's making design choices for the user, which follows the whole Ruby and Rails philosophy.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't realize that.